# SWIZ: Getting started with first example

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, swiz

I am trying to start with the framework, but it appears to be
dramatically hard for some reason. I want to follow complete example
posted here
http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Quick+Start

But I have issue on the very beginning. E.g.

```
       <swiz:beanProviders>
           <config:Beans />
       </swiz:beanProviders>
```

The line  causes the error:
The prefix "config" for element "config:Bean" is not bound.
SwizTest.mxml   /SwizTest/src   line 10 Flex Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably just missing the *namespace declaration* for the config:  part of config:Beans. Flex basically doesn't know what package or folder config prefix is pointing to unless you have that.

If you look at the application node at the top of the example I think you'll see what's missing:
    `<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:view="org.swizframework.quickswiz.view.*"
    xmlns:config="org.swizframework.quickswiz.config.*"
    xmlns:swiz="http://swiz.swizframework.org"`>

Hope that does the trick.